# How to setup PHPUnit test with multi module setup of phalcon?

Tags: phpunit, phalcon

I have created a test application with single setup and used PHPUnit as per tutorial http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/unit-testing.html and it works well.

Can anybody help me how do I setup it for multi module setup?

Answer (score 1):

Unit test  doesnt care whether  apps is single or multimodule. Given example just given  DI and config in test suite. For example if you want to test AddUser function in UserModule, you have to create User object and mock its dependency. then call it in unit test.

```
$user = new \App\Module\User\User.php;
$this->assertTrue($user->addUser());
```